# Print in object oriented programming ( OX )

Tags: oop, ox

I am using a language called OX. It's an objected oriented matrix programming language. I am new to OOP. I have a few elementary questions.  Since the language does not have a debug mode, I need to print out variables to debug. Please correct me if I am wrong in the following statement.

1. If I define a variable in the header file, say P1. And the class is MNP. Then in my main function, I could print the variable as print (MNP::P1) .
2. When an source is compiled as an object file, the print command in the object file will not be shown in the output window. So the only way to print is in the main function.

I am very new to the language. I am not sure if I have provided all information. Please correct me if I am not giving enough information.

Comment: Why did you tag it as C++ instead of, say, OX?

Comment: I think the way OX structured is most close to C++

Comment: I removed the C++ tag since it seems quite irrelevant.

Comment: In your second point, what do you mean by "the print command in the object file will not be shown in the output window"? Are you just compiling or executing the function in the object file?

Answer (score 0):

1.
There is a decent [documentation](http://www.doornik.com/ox/oxsyntax.html#ox_syntax_RefClasses). As far as I understood it `MNP::P1` will not compile. The reason is, that a class only defines what an object looks like. In this case any object of class `MNP` will have a member `P1`. However, the class itself has no objects, therefore `MNP::P1` is not a variable you can print. In C++ you could make `P1` static, but that is not supported in OX. Instead you need to make an object like so:

```
decl mnpobj = new MNP(0);
print(mnpobj.P1);
```

Make sure that `P1` inside of `class MNP` is declared `public`, otherwise you will get some kind of access violation error message.

Point 2. may come later.